# Visual Basic split function

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, data-structures, split

Ok so now I'm not getting an error but instead of everything being posted in the listbox it only contains the first line of text from the .txt file. This is the code I changed it too:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader

    If IO.File.Exists("StudentList.txt") = True Then
        inFile = IO.File.OpenText("StudentList.txt")
        For index As Integer = 0 To inFile.Peek = -1
            Dim splits = inFile.ReadLine.Split(","c)
            Member(index).ID = splits(0)
            Member(index).lastName = splits(1)
            Member(index).firstName = splits(2)
            Member(index).middleName = splits(3)
            Member(index).grade = splits(4)
            Member(index).period = splits(5)

            ListBox1.Items.Add(Member(index).ID.PadLeft(10) & " " & Member(index).lastName & " " & Member(index).firstName)

        Next
        inFile.Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("error", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Split() is almost always a horrible way to handle csv data.

Comment: You are getting into trouble with your unusual For statement.  Somewhat inevitably, you forgot to increase *index*.

Comment: @Hans how is it unusual? Even after adding index after next it's still the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to assign a string array to a `Member`. That is, you have:

```
Member(index) = infile.ReadLine.Split(",", c);
```

You need to assign each field:

```
Dim splits = infile.ReadLine.Split(",", c);

Member(index).ID = splits(0);
Member(index).lastName = splits(1);
... etc.
```

### Update after OP edit

I suspect the problem now is that your `For` loop is executing only once, or `index` isn't being incremented. I don't know where you came up with that wonky `infile.Peek = -1` thing, but I suspect it doesn't work the way you think it does. Use something more conventional, like this.

```
Dim index As Integer = 0
For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("StudentList.txt")
    Dim splits = line.Split(",", c)
    Member(index).ID = splits(0)
    ' etc.
    ListBox1.Add(...)
    Index = Index + 1
Next
```

Comment: Ok so I changed the code and I'm still getting an error.

Comment: @DarkBlue: Edit your question and tell us what error you're getting. Copy the *exact* error message, and tell us on what line you get the error.

Comment: says "File is not declared" was I suppose to declare that as a string?

Comment: @DarkBlue: "File is not declared" probably isn't the complete error message. Try `System.IO.File.ReadLines`. Also look up the [Imports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx) statement for Visual Basic. As in `Imports System.IO`, which will save you a little typing in the future.